# Shorter method for concatenating strings in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, concatenation

Suppose we have some string prefix and suffix that we want to reuse.

```
prefix = "My name is "
suffix = "Nice to meet you."
for name in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    print(prefix + name + suffix)
```

Is there any way to write the code above in a more succinct way, such that variable substitution can be done on an instance for a single string instance, similar to the `f"{var}"` method, but with the string being an instance?

Comment: What do you mean with "the string being an instance"? What's wrong with `f"{prefix}{name}{suffix}"`?

Comment: To my understanding f"{var}" is a constructor. But can I do something like `s = "{}"; s.format('put this inside the bracket')`

Comment: You can do exactly `s = "{}"` ; `s.format('put this inside the bracket')` if that is what you're asking. But `f"{var}"` is not a constructor, and I'm not sure what you think that means.

Comment: `f"{prefix}{name}{suffix} "` This works for what I want. I just didn't think of it at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python strings are immutable. Therefore you will have to create a new one each time. Sorry :(
As for shorter code, you could use list comprehension or map to make it into a single line:

```
[prefix + name + suffix for name in ['A','B', 'C']]
```

Comment: "Python strings are immutable." is exactly the thing I needed to hear. Using the `f"{prefix}{name}{suffix}"` string interpolation method is what solved my problem. Thanks.